# HiveQL is cutting zeros from fields

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, sqoop

when I bring some data to the hive, it ends up cutting the 0 both at the beginning and at the end, normally this data comes from a document.

However, the CPF comes with 11 digits and the CNPJ comes with 14, and when the data is entered in the table, it ends up cutting the zeros (depending on the document, it can be at the beginning or at the end), how can I avoid this problem even though I understand that can you enter two types of documents in the column?

Measuring shell size with LEGTH doesn't work, because of these cuts in zeros.

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: Show us some sample table data, the current result, and the wanted result. (All as formatted text, no images, no links.)

Comment: Column data type: String

Comment: document > 0011111111111 –-> 11111111111, 000222222872 --> 222222872

Comment: if target table column type is also string, it should not cut it. What may cut is a tool which you are using to display data. For example excel with number column

Comment: Hello everyone, how can I make a SQL to not remove the 0 on the left and the right? Type: 00247829100

Comment: i think the data type is converted to bigint. so i dont thinnk its removing 0 from the end but from the beginning. possible to change data type?